# Аттрибуты radio checked

Tags: javascript, теги, атрибуты, radio-input

Интересует следующий вопрос: есть ли какой-нибудь обратный атрибут у радио checked.

```
document.getElementById('radio').checked;
```

Только что-то из серии no-checked может быть. Нужно для того чтобы отключать кнопку перехода к следующему вопросу пока не выбран вариант ответа

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В JS это будет:

```js
!document.getElementById('radio').checked;
```

В CSS:

```css
input[type="radio"]:not(:checked){}
```